# dtype='numeric' is not compatible with arrays of bytes/strings with streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, streamlit

```py
import numpy as np
import pickle
import streamlit


loaded_model=pickle.load(open("C:/Users/pranj/Desktop/titanic/titanic_trained_model.pkl",'rb'))


input_data=(3,0,22.000000,1,0,7.2500,0)

#channging the input data in numpy array
input_data_as_numpy_arr=np.asarray(input_data)

# reshape the array as we are predicting for one instance
input_data_reshaped=input_data_as_numpy_arr.reshape(1,-1)


prediction=loaded_model.predict(input_data_reshaped)
print(prediction)
if (prediction[0]==0):
    print("The person will die")
else:
    print("The person will not die")
```

If you run this code, it will run without any errors. However, when I try to make a website using streamlit, I get an error.

```py
import numpy as np
import pickle
import streamlit as st

#loading the saved model
loaded_model=pickle.load(open("C:/Users/pranj/Desktop/titanic/titanic_trained_model.pkl",'rb'))


# creating a function
def diabetes_predection(input_data):
    
    #changing the input data in numpy array
    input_data_as_numpy_arr=np.asarray(input_data)

# reshape the array as we are predicting for one instance
    input_data_reshaped=input_data_as_numpy_arr.reshape(1,-1)
    prediction=loaded_model.predict(input_data_reshaped)
    print(prediction)
    if (prediction[0]==0):
        return "The person will die"       
    else:
        return "The person will not die"


def main():
    # giving title 
    st.title('Titanic Prediction Web App')
    
    # getting the input data from the users
    Pclass=st.text_input('Pclass 1st class/2nd class/3rd class')
    Sex=st.text_input('Sex Put 0 for male 1 for female')
    Age=st.text_input('Age')
    SibSp=st.text_input('SibSp')
    Parch=st.text_input('Parch')
    Fare=st.text_input('Fare')
    Embarked=st.text_input('Embarked Press 0 for Southampton,1 for Cherbourg,2 for Queenstown')
    
    #code for Prediction
    Survived=""
    
    # creating button for prediction
    if st.button('Survived Test Result'):
        Survived=diabetes_predection([Pclass,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Fare,Embarked])
    
    st.success(Survived)
    
    
main()
```

The error I get is:

> dtype='numeric' is not compatible with arrays of bytes/strings. Convert your data to numeric values explicitly instead.

Can someone explain why does this error occur and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The return type of st.text_input('param') is a string. Please ensure that you convert your features into compatible data types.

Comment: I couldn't understand what are you telling plz pin my code where i have done mistake

Comment: This user means that, for example, the line `Age=st.text_input('Age')` makes the variable `Age` a string in python. If you input `30` when running the python code, then `Age` has value `"30"`. It is not `30` (a number). So you would need to convert `"30"` to `30`.

Comment: I still confuse in this i am not saying that you are wrong but previously I make a model on 'diabetes during pregnancy ' on that all my values are numeric but i used st.text_input now in this model where there is required i used encoding in categorical value and then use st.text_input .                                                                                                               Main part is that i couldn't understand where i have to use st.text_input and st.number_input.

Comment: Just make an numpy array of the features that you get from st.text_input() and change the type to `int` if all your variables are integer data types of if it is not the case do it manually before passing it to your model for prediction.